# Find the generalized Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis

the following question is in second edition of "Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems" by Churchill.

> If a function $f$ has a representation $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n \ g_n(x)$ on a fundamental interval $(a,b)$ which the set $\{ g_n \}$ is orthogonal, but not normalized, $0 < || g_n || \neq 1$. Use the inner products to show formally that $A_n = \frac{(f,g_n)}{||g_n||^2}$.
>
> $\textbf{My attempt:}$
>
> $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n \ g_n(x)$
>
> $\Longrightarrow \langle f,g_m \rangle = \langle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n \ g_n(x),g_m(x) \rangle$
>
> $\Longrightarrow \langle f,g_m \rangle = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \langle A_n \ g_n(x),g_m(x) \rangle$
>
> $\Longrightarrow \langle f,g_m \rangle = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n \langle g_n(x),g_m(x) \rangle$
>
> $\Longrightarrow \langle f,g_m \rangle = A_m$

I would like to know if my attempt is wrong or if the statement of the question is wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is wrong. As the problem states, the $\{g_n\}$ are not orthonormal, just orthogonal. So 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \langle g_n(x), g_m(x)\rangle= A_m \|g_m\|^2.$$

Now you can conclude.

Comment: I can not believe I missed this. Thanks a lot!